# Multiple IPs on Juniper SRX100 Untrust Port

Tags: firewall, juniper

I am having trouble getting multiple IP addresses on the untrust port. I have tried a few different methods, but can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have a good tutorial that is not easily found or if possible can type up the steps?  I don't mind trying to do it through ssh, but would prefer web interface.

Thank you

```
 fe-0/0/0 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {
            dhcp {
                update-server;
            }
        }
    }
}

routing-options {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 96.11.173.81;
    }
}
```

Right now it's setup to receive settings from 'cable modem' through dhcp, but I think it's only getting one IP.

Comment: Can you show me your interface config?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about through the web interface, but it's simple enough in the cli. You just set the address multiple times.

Here's the commands.

First if you ssh as root you'll need to start the cli.

```
# cli
```

Then enter config mode.

```
> config
```

Set the config.

```
set interfaces fe-0/0/1 description External
set interfaces fe-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.1.1/24
set interfaces fe-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.2.1/24
set security zones security-zone untrust interfaces fe-0/0/1.0
```

Finally save and quit.

```
commit and-quit
```

When you run show the config you'll see this:

```
interfaces {
    fe-0/0/1 {
        description External;
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.1.1/24;
                address 192.168.2.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
security {
    zones {
        security-zone untrust {
            interfaces {
                fe-0/0/1.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally, you'll want to replace the IP's and interface names with the ones that you really want to use.

I have not taken into account any routing or security policies. You'll need to add those as well.

So just to put it more simply, the default mode is to add multiple IP addresses. Just issue the set command multiple times. In order to *change* an IP you have to delete the old one.

Comment: When I do this - I lose internet connectivity.  Is there a common reason for that?  fe-0/0/0.0 - replaced two ips with two of my five

routing-options {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop xx.xx.xxx.xx;
    }
}

Comment: Until you get it set up you should be on the same subnet so that doesn't happen. I would need to see the rest of the config and need to know your computer's IP. Can you attach/post the config? Use `show conf` to get the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will set one IP and proxy-arp the rest on the interface.... ie:

set security nat proxy-arp interface ge-0/0/0 67.34.52.15/32

Comment: This gives me a syntax error when trying to put in the IP address. Tried 
++++++++++++
set security nat proxy-arp interface fe-0/0/0 67.34.52.15/32 -- I replaced the 67 ip with one of my external ips, but not the one that was assigned to the main interface. IE, IP address #2 from my block. root@buzzlebee-dev-01# set security nat proxy-arp interface fe-0/0/0.0 96.11.173.83/32 error: syntax error: 96.11.173.83/32

Comment: You may not need to add the /32 when you input it, that may be done for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a break down here with the syntax check, or a limitation of being unable to set proxy-arp while using a DHCP address.

Proxy-arp addresses need to be members of a subnet bound to the interface in question. Since you're obtaining the address using DHCP, the check portion of commit is probably flagging any address you place in a proxy-arp statement as out of bounds with the subnet configured on the interface.

You will most likely need to migrate to static addressing on your interface, as bahamat outlined.